# PowerBI Table and Matrix Totals/SubTotals Not Summing Properly

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm doing some very basic aggregations and this is the issue I'm facing,

[image]

The total simply doesn't add up to what it's supposed to be. Is this a table relationship issue or something else?

That total makes sense without any filters applied.

Comment: I don't see how this question can be answered without knowing your data model  and formulas.

Comment: I've managed to work it out. It was mainly a data issue, relationships are good.

Answer (score 1):

What might have happened is that the relationship was only filtered in one direction. To fix this, follow these steps:

- Click through to the **Home** tab > **Manage Relationships**
- Click on the relationship describing *Spend* to the filtered table causing the problem
- Click on **Edit...**
- Ensure the *Cross filter direction* drop-down is set to **Both**

Hopefully that works for you!

Answer (score -2):

Managed to figure this out by looking at the data in on a very detailed level. Turns out the relationships are fine, it was just a matter of bad data that caused the relationships to be wonky and bring in other values.